# alternative methods for ELT in datastage?

Tags: datastage

Is ELT possible in Datastage by using join,aggregate components ( without running directly a SQL statement from a database stage or by calling a stored procedure?)

Example:
In oracle db, i have a sql as shown below.
In IBM datastage, is it possible to run this sql with etl components( without running directly a SQL statement from a database stage or by calling a stored procedure)

insert into trg1
select
cust_expense.cust_id, cust.cust_name,
cust_expense.month, sum(cust_expense.expense)
from cust_expense, cust
group by
cust_expense.cust_id, cust.cust_name,
cust_expense.month

Comment: Provide more background - how should transformations within the database be possible without SQL?

Comment: Is this about the IBM DataStage tool? We have a number of stages are available in DataStage to perform ETL operations. Can you please be more specific about what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: I ve added an example, I have two source tables and one target table in same database. I will use join and  'group by' components of datastage. However, this job runs like etl job. It will take data to etl tool engine then insert target table. I would like to run this job directly on database like running sql stamement on db.

Comment: Do you mean to use stages to generate SQL that will then run at the database without actually fetching or sending content? The only thing that comes into my mind is try using the [Datastage Balanced Optimization](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.3?topic=jobs-introduction-infosphere-datastage-balanced-optimization), but I don't know if that can optimize a job down to zero data trasmissions. Just give it a try.

Comment: @JustusKenklies , Exactly this is what i m asking. I will use datastage components and it will generate sql and run on database (without fetching data).

Comment: Well, as I said, the only thing I can think of is balanced optimization, which tries to optimize your job at design time. AFAIK, doing that can change your job in a way that may remove some stages and put their tasks into an SQL. But if you already know what SQL you need, then you'd probably be faster and more precise doing that directly in an oracle stage, since the optimizer would also put it right there, anyways. So the simple answer to your question would be a simple 'no', I guess.